# Print function in Python is printing results on new lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently writing a basic dice ware password generator. I am having an issue when printing the final password combination. The string I am printing is printing each word on a new line instead of the whole string on one line. I am not too sure why.

My code is as follows:

```
import random

finalPass=""

def choosePass():
    global finalPass
    i=0
    j=0
    while(i<=5):
        num=""
        num=str(random.randint(1,6))
        while(j<4):
            num=num+str(random.randint(1,6))
            j+=1
        f=open('container', 'r')
        for line in f:
            if(line[0:5]==num):
                line=line[6::]
                line=line.replace(' ','')
                #Add the new word to the string of old words
                finalPass+=str(line,)
        f.close()
        j=0
        i+=1
    #This is printing each word to a new line. I want it to print to the same line
    print(finalPass)

choosePass()
```

Comment: please fix your post

Comment: sorry new to the site :) have added a code window

Comment: put `line.strip()` to strip all whitespace from the line. the way that `open()` works as an iterator is it reads until it hits a new line character which means that every `line` will have a new line character at the end of it.

Comment: What do you think `finalPass+=str(line,)` does? You add the string representation of a `tuple` to your password and I don't believe that is what you want.

Comment: even better!...i didn't know that line.strip existed. Thank you!

Comment: i have removed the , from the line. I was reading up on my issue on google and someone suggested adding the , to prevent it from going to a  new line. As i said, I'm only few weeks into learning python so I'm fairly new to this

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all "\n" symbols on " " in finalPass string before printing

And i wnat give you advice - before ask any question try to find answer in python docs and search your question on stackoverflow archive.

Comment: thank you! i didn't think to replace \n with ''. This has fixed it :)

Comment: still doesn't tell me why it was printing to a new line each time tho. Anyone got any ideas

Comment: Yes, but it's a useful information for junior.
Try to replace all "\n" symbols @Kiro!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Thought i would share the finale more efficient version of the code!

```js
import random

password=""

def choosePass():
    global password
    for i in range(0,6):
        num=""
        for j in range(0,5):
            num=num+str(random.randint(1,6))
        f=open('container','r')
        for line in f:
            if(line[0:5]==num):
                line=line[6::].strip()
                password+=line+' '
        f.close()
    print(password+''+str(random.randint(100,1000)))

choosePass()
```